# Hardhat TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider') on getContractFactory

Tags: typescript, smartcontracts, nft, hardhat

I'm having a hard time to spot what is the error here.
We are using simple command line to trigger hardhat tasks.
I also tried to use a different [syntax](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/deploying) but it fails too.
Here is the code:

```
task("deploy-erc271a-contract", "Deploy ERC271A Mint NFT contract", async (taskArgs, hre) => {    
      console.log("Task[deploy-erc271a-contract] getContractFactory for MyERC271A");
      const nftERC271AFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyERC271A");

      // Start deployment, returning a promise that resolves to a contract object
      console.log("Task[deploy-erc271a-contract] Contract deploying... ");

      //Contract takes: name, symbol, delegates[], receivers[], amount[]
      const nftERC271AContract = await nftERC271AFactory.deploy(taskArgs.name, taskArgs.symbol);
      await nftERC271AContract.deployed();

      console.log("Task[deploy-erc271a-contract] Contract deployed: " + nftERC271AContract.address)
      return(nftERC271AContract.address);
 });
```

With this code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/iii/dev/impulse-sk/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:4:61)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/iii/dev/impulse-sk/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/provider-proxy.ts:7:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
```

Any idea?

Comment: `hardhat.config.js` might not be set correctly

Comment: Thanks ! I'll go through the tutorial again but do you have advices on what I should look at precisely?

Comment: You might not connected to any network. Maybe your default network is ganache but ganache is not running

Comment: that was not it. The new version had different methods that I could check in the "init" project. After migrating my code to the new one, it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to `ethers@5.7.2` solved it for me.